# Ionic/React/TypeScript, react-router navigation Animation triggers twice

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router

So basically i'm Working on a Ionic/React Typescript application and there is this strange page transition that occurs twice when I navigate thought the app (see gif below)

I checked and it's not the renders that's call twice as the componentWillMount/didMount/willUnmount are all trigger once like it should for the pusher page and also for the pushed page.

[image]

As you can see, the transition always happens twice and found no solution anywhere ... Versions used : - Ionic : 5.2.1 - React : 16.9.0 (npm package) - Typescript 3.6.3 (npm package)

```
Here is the code for the page with the "Diplomes" Title:

class Diplome extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps> {

  // Function who redirect to the url for edit an situation
  redirectUrlToEditSituation = () => {
    this.props.history.push('/app/edit/diplome/', null);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <IonPage>
          <IonHeader>
            <IonToolbar>
                <ButtonHambToolBar />
                <ToolBarLogo toolbarName={ToolBarName.DIPLOME}/>
            </IonToolbar>
          </IonHeader>
          <IonContent>
            <FabButtonAction ClickHandler={() => this.redirectUrlToEditSituation()} icon={add}/>
            <GenericList type={ModelType.DIPLOME}/>
          </IonContent>
      </IonPage>
    );
  }
}

export default (Diplome);
```

And here is the page with the "Editions" title when click on the button :

```
class DiplomeEdit extends Component<DiplomeEditProps, {
    dataIsLoad: boolean,
    label_field: string,
    isAnCreate: boolean,
    openModalDelete: boolean,
    isValidation: boolean,
    currentDiplome: any
}>
{

    constructor(props: DiplomeEditProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            label_field: '',
            isAnCreate: true,
            openModalDelete: false,
            dataIsLoad: false,
            currentDiplome: '',
            isValidation: false,
        };
    }

    async componentWillMount() {
        console.log("component will mount");
        await this.getCurrentDiplomeToUpdate();
    }

    // Function who check if they are param on the url
    // If param exist get the current diplome on the store
    getCurrentDiplomeToUpdate = async () => {
        if (this.props.match.params.idDiplome !== undefined) {

            const diplomes: DiplomeInterface[] = this.props.diplomes;
            if (diplomes.length > 0) {
                const currentDiplomeReceive: DiplomeInterface | undefined = diplomes.find((res: DiplomeInterface) => {
                    return this.props.match.params.idDiplome === res.idDiplome;
                });

                if (currentDiplomeReceive !== undefined) {
                    this.setState({
                        isAnCreate: false,
                        label_field: currentDiplomeReceive.labelDiplome,
                        currentDiplome: currentDiplomeReceive,
                        dataIsLoad: true,
                    });
                }
            }

        } else {
            this.setState({
                isAnCreate: true,
                dataIsLoad: true,
            });
        }
    }

    // Function who render update button
    renderUpdateButton = () => {
        return (
            <div className="contenaire_button_action_situation_edit">
                <Button hidden={this.state.isAnCreate}
                    onClick={() => this.openOrCloseModalDeleteDialog()}
                    className="button_delete_situation">Supprimer</Button>
                <Button
                    onClick={e => this.actionClick()}
                    className="button_action_situation_edit">Enregistrer</Button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    // Function who delete diplome on the databse and on the store
    removeDiplome = async () => {
        await REQUEST.deleteDiplome(this.state.currentDiplome.idDiplome);
        store.dispatch(DELETE_DIPLOME(this.state.currentDiplome.idDiplome));
        this.props.history.replace('/app/diplomes');
    }

    // Function who get the label and id for create new diplome on the databae
    // Reset the state to the default init
    saveDiplome = async () => {
        const obj: DiplomeInterface = {
            idDiplome: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9),
            labelDiplome: this.state.label_field.toLowerCase(),
        };
        this.setState({
            label_field: '',
            isAnCreate: false,
            openModalDelete: false,
        });
        await REQUEST.postDiplome(obj);
        store.dispatch(ADD_DIPLOME(obj));
        //this.props.history.replace('/app/diplomes');
        window.smartAlert("Diplome ajouté avec succès", "success", 5000);
        this.props.history.goBack();
    }

    // Function who update a diplome on the store
    // Need the current diplome
    // Label update
    updateDiplome = async () => {
        const currentDiplomeReceive: DiplomeInterface = this.state.currentDiplome;

        const obj: DiplomeInterface = {
            idDiplome: currentDiplomeReceive.idDiplome,
            labelDiplome: this.state.label_field,
        };

        if (this.props.userConnected.typeAccount === TypeConnect.ADMIN) {
            await REQUEST.updateDiplome(obj);
            store.dispatch(UPDATE_DIPLOME(obj));
            this.props.history.replace('/app/diplomes');
        }
    }

    // Function who checked what action we need
    actionClick = () => {
        if (this.state.isAnCreate) {
            this.saveDiplome();
        } else {
            this.updateDiplome();
        }
    }

    // Function call when input change
    inputChange = (e: any) => {
        this.setState({
            label_field: e.target.value,
        });
    }

    // Function who change the openModalDelete to true
    openOrCloseModalDeleteDialog = () => {
        if (this.props.userConnected.typeAccount === TypeConnect.ADMIN) {
            this.setState({
                openModalDelete: !this.state.openModalDelete,
            });
        }
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <IonPage>
                <IonHeader>
                    <IonToolbar className="task_cat_toolbar">
                        <IonBackButton
                            className="situation_edit_back_button" />
                        <ToolBarLogo toolbarName={ToolBarName.EDIT} />
                    </IonToolbar>
                </IonHeader>

                <IonContent>
                    <div className="contenaire_edit">
                        <div className="contenaire_form_situation">
                            <div className="contenaire_field">
                                <TextField
                                    onChange={e => this.inputChange(e)}
                                    value={this.state.label_field}
                                    className="field_form_situation"
                                    label="Libelle" />
                            </div>

                            <div className="container_task_situation_edit">

                                {!this.state.dataIsLoad && <SpinnerCircular />}

                                {this.renderUpdateButton()}

                                {
                                    this.state.openModalDelete &&
                                    <DialogDelete
                                        actionRemove={() => this.removeDiplome()}
                                        open={this.state.openModalDelete}
                                        actionCloseModal={() => this.openOrCloseModalDeleteDialog()} />
                                }

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </IonContent>

            </IonPage>
        );
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state: DiplomeEditProps) => ({
    diplomes: state.diplomes,
    network: state.network,
    role: state.role,
    userConnected: state.userConnected,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DiplomeEdit);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem. It seems Ionic React does not go well with history and location props. [check out this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/20365).

I managed to get around my issue by wrapping my component with React.memo and instead of using history to push, I used Redirect from react-router-dom with a state to redirect.